# Angular2: Html replace empty

Tags: angular

I have an dynamically generated list of items generated as follows:

```
<div class="servers" *ngFor="let item of products">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>{{item}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

There are cases when item can be equal to blank, or nothing.

I want to use an easy nG method to replace the empty value with something concrete. (UNKNOWN in this case)

I have tried to do something like this:

```
<td class="headings" ng-if="{{item}}">{{item}}</td>
<td class="headings" ng-if="{{!item}}">Unknown</td>
```

But this yields in an error:

```
Can't bind to 'ng-if' since it isn't a known property of 'td'
```

If I remove the {{}} expression, all items get a UNKNOWN

```
<td class="headings" ng-if="item">{{item}}</td>
<td class="headings" ng-if="!item">Unknown</td>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is `*ngIf="expression"`.

Comment: sigh, that was it. can't believe i over looked it